# How do I import into ADAM / AD LDS - The specified instance type is invalid

Tags: windows, active-directory, ad-lds, ldif, adam

I'm having a hard time importing an LDIF file into ADAM/ AD LDS, and the error is below (instance type is invalid).

I've tested and recovered from errors that relate to

- The import file is ASCII, UTF8, ANSI
- Invalid properties in the import file (MS Internal objects for replication)
- In AD the name of the users container is an `CN`, in ADAM it's "OU"
- Changed the test object class from `contact` to `user` in maker.ldf
- misc errors..

My overall goal is to move certificate data from ADDS to AD LDS, and expose that read only LDS copy to the world.

I've now hit a wall and am stuck, unable to import a certificate into the instance.  To ensure that I'm doing things logically correct, I'm doing an export and an import, as shown below.

**Question**

- How do I import the data as show in Import sample?

**EXPORT SAMPLE**

Command line

```
PS C:\test> ldifde -f .\test.ldf -v -s 127.0.0.1  -d "DC= FreeSMIME, DC=COM"
Connecting to "127.0.0.1"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Exporting directory to file .\maker.ldf
Searching for entries...
Writing out entries
 .... SNIP ... 
Exporting entry: CN=test12,OU=Users,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com

9 entries exported
```

Contents of test.ldf

```
dn: CN=test12,OU=Users,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: test12
distinguishedName: CN=test12,OU=Users,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20140706175425.0Z
whenChanged: 20140706175425.0Z
uSNCreated: 13981
uSNChanged: 13981
name: test12
objectGUID:: FGuCH4ep+0yvXyXIGZnw6Q==
badPwdCount: 0
badPasswordTime: 0
pwdLastSet: 130491428650358040
objectSid:: AQUAAB/DvlvT9kQDKv5c3yyu4EqPUic3jHkmDg==
objectCategory: 
 CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={EBB3EB07-5375-4D67-B774-42E7D82935A8}
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
msDS-UserAccountDisabled: TRUE
```

**IMPORT SAMPLE**

Command line

> PS C:\test> ldifde -i -k -f .\maker.ldf -v -s 127.0.0.1 Connecting to
>   "127.0.0.1" Logging in as current user using SSPI Importing directory
>   from file ".\maker.ldf" Loading entries 1: DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
>
> Add error on entry starting on line 1: Unwilling To Perform The server
>   side error is: 0x2079 The specified instance type is not valid. The
>   extended server error is: 00002079: SvcErr: DSID-033309B0, problem
>   5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
>
> 0 entries modified successfully. An error has occurred in the program
>   No log files were written.  In order to generate a log file, please
>   specify the log file path via the -j option.

Contents of maker.ldf

```
dn: CN=makerofthings7@me.com,OU=Users,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: makerofthings7@me.com
userCertificate:: 
 MIIFUTCCBDmgAwIBAgITHwAAADzW+zggKBd9dQABAAAAPDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB0MQswCQYDVQ
 QGEwJ1czEVMBMGA1UEChMMQml0Y2xlYXIgTExDMRYwFAYDVQQLEw1FbWFpbCBQcml2YWN5MRYwFAYD
 VQQDEw1GcmVlU01JTUUuY29tMR4wHAYDVQQDExVTZWN1cmUgSXNzdWVyIDAxYS0wMDEwHhcNMTQwNz
 A2MDQyNDQyWhcNMTUwMTAyMDQyNDQyWjCBgzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAk5ZMQwwCgYD
 VQQHEwNOWUMxEzARBgNVBAsTClRlY2hub2xvZ3kxHjAcBgNVBAMMFW1ha2Vyb2Z0aGluZ3M3QG1lLm
 NvbTEkMCIGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYVbWFrZXJvZnRoaW5nczdAbWUuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF
 AAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAymz3YPRVAE2i1X7XmmrBk+SmsH1FAyYEhNkKpDn6R+1Za8n5OC4UseQwCs
 HoM/PtZ50JYViPW1+qBykehkH4LylCkp5OIjZbodedcIL+ucDHh1PITNChp8C5fQWYmfiUofWF8ztA
 yGJNriy9VO30JFq9xexnif7i04kxdd151/BjOW5FEGOrpZJajoLkQycfbtdexxrKvGbSNsZZ4dwKVy
 uxRcXXwgT9p8wa51uMGMBdpFsKTRkmFl8nvx1zRdcGfl7CkKLCRmZkoCPP+vgyqGUtO+bYxSP6vc0t
 hZ7efXOkoDQWMfj/EHcKGWJgGm4B+l4SG9Pfkujr+Miw1CxHvwIDAQABo4IByjCCAcYwPQYJKwYBBA
 GCNxUHBDAwLgYmKwYBBAGCNxUIgq30IYfppWqGlZ8EhYL3L4GCyxkhhZLlIIb5vHACAWQCAQ4wEwYD
 VR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwQwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgUgMBsGCSsGAQQBgjcVCgQOMAwwCgYIKwYBBQ
 UHAwQwRAYJKoZIhvcNAQkPBDcwNTAOBggqhkiG9w0DAgICAIAwDgYIKoZIhvcNAwQCAgCAMAcGBSsO
 AwIHMAoGCCqGSIb3DQMHMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSruXcob9eIxbsorVGMF6m+w7LACTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgB
 TaxAaP6+QX4fmgA8d0h36ZY/fwRjBNBgNVHR8ERjBEMEKgQKA+hjxodHRwOi8vcGtpLmJpdGNsZWFy
 LnVzL2kwMWEvU2VjdXJlJTIwSXNzdWVyJTIwMDFhLTAwMSgxKS5jcmwwbgYIKwYBBQUHAQEEYjBgMF
 4GCCsGAQUFBzAChlJodHRwOi8vcGtpLmJpdGNsZWFyLnVzL2kwMWEvYS5Jc3N1ZTAxLmJpdGNsZWFy
 LnVzX1NlY3VyZSUyMElzc3VlciUyMDAxYS0wMDEoMSkuY3J0MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQA/6K
 tRc0Nq5hdJouyTMNMUju+DW2Px2gVfAx6h7UWdG76FVJ14CuTCuS0zLngmO102eeTo9//ZOKE5UcdP
 JmlegIam0ne8uNELInIY8HancU5fW34O+Jxa/ZqOMzXiHyKwTC4dwBsgP0TjHQsnYzSIAM/pB7fpBw
 FYUeqcz3XmsjbasQazCotCuAXIIPaqW2hC7KbEXDCaCdLAWWQ8erd+CeNmmclP5GXi2ZvxVDOW8l/F
 nGRQSrMTkZz4Rc2jS9w6VlGBMR+GXPQ9rJmxSl89WLATsejYFbDwbM5nKGJfpTZVf1SYnKGb9ficVu
 eHeuwv1fGAV4s9zHSCsk33EElS
distinguishedName: 
 CN=makerofthings7@me.com,CN=Users,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
instanceType: 4
name: makerofthings7@me.com 
objectCategory: 
 CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
mail: makerofthings7@me.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the import file by removing the line:

```
objectCategory: 
 CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=FreeSMIME,DC=com
```